# External monitor(s) not working via HDMI from macbook

Tags: mac, external-display, osx-yosemite

Ok, disclaimer, I am not a mac person, but my wife uses one.  She needed a space at home, so I picked up 2 (used) acer monitors for her.  The macbook has the mini-DP and HDMI outs.  The mini-DP, even with an adapter works just fine, but the HDMI does not output anything to those 2 monitors, even when it's the only one plugged in.
The thing is is that it shows the Acer as connected on the MB, just no output.  I've tried the trick of holding down option and see "detect displays" but it doesn't change anything.

I have tested my laptop (windows) on the monitors (with the same cable) and it works fine.
I have tested the macbook on my TV and that works, so it's not the output itself.
I've messed around with the Hertz and the resolution.
So.. I don't think it's hardware, but what else could it be?  We've even done the apparently taboo practice of restarting the mac to no avail. 
As usual the apple forums are a mix of unhelpful and denial that the issue could possible exist, so any help is appreciated.

*Edit*
Oh, it's an MBP from "mid-2014", Retina 15" and running 10.10.5 (and is up to date) with the Intel Iris pro 1536 MB graphics and the monitors are Acer H233H

Comment: We'd really need to know the precise Mac model, OS version & Monitor model to even start to guess. You can look up Macs using [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com) even by serial number if you need to.

Comment: I've updated the specs

Comment: Is there any reason you're stuck on 10.10.5? The upgrades are free and there could well have been a lot of bug fixes in the last two years.

Comment: Also, did you try swapping out the HDMI cable?

Comment: Not sure about the version, but probably because 10.11 had so many issued when it came out she didn't do it.

Comment: And yes, tried 2 HDMI cables

Comment: According to http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.2-15-iris-only-mid-2014-retina-display-specs.html it ought to work, so I'm not really sure. It ought to be able to run both off Thunderbolt/MiniDP, so maybe look at that as a workaround.

Comment: Oh really, I'm guessing it's just a splitter? Cool I'll look into that.